# GetMenuString does not return the string of a submenu

Tags: winapi, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm creating a menu for my application's tray icon, and one of the items has a submenu that I want to apply the OwnerDraw attribute to. The menu displays and works correctly when drawn normally, but when I try to draw it myself, the background of the items does draw as required, but I can't retrieve the string assigned to the item to draw it (causing the items to be displayed "blank").

Here is my drawing code:

```pascal
procedure DrawOpaMenuItem(Menu: HMENU; DC: HDC; itemID: Cardinal; itemRect: TRect; State: Cardinal);
var
  Text: PWideChar;
  TxtLen: Integer;
  FNT: HFONT;
  BkBrush: HBRUSH;
begin
  SetTextColor(DC, GetSysColor(COLOR_MENUTEXT));
  SetBkMode(DC, TRANSPARENT);
  FNT := GetMenuFont; //A function that uses SystemParametersInfo with SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS to create a font based on lfMenuFont
  SelectObject(DC, FNT);
  BkBrush := CreateSolidBrush(RGB($40,$F0,$FF));

  if State and ODS_SELECTED = 1 then
    FillRect(DC, itemRect, GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT))
  else
    FillRect(DC, itemRect, BkBrush);

  itemRect.Left := itemRect.Left + 10;

  TxtLen := GetMenuString(Menu, itemID, nil, 0, MF_BYCOMMAND); //returns only 0!!!

  if TxtLen <> 0 then
  begin
    GetMenuString(Menu, itemID, Text, TxtLen + 1, MF_BYCOMMAND);
    DrawTextEx(DC, Text, -1, itemRect, DT_SINGLELINE or DT_VCENTER, nil);
  end
  else
    DrawTextEx(DC, PWideChar('Item'), -1, itemRect, DT_SINGLELINE or DT_VCENTER, nil);

  DeleteObject(BkBrush);
  DeleteObject(FNT);
  SetBkMode(DC, BKMODE_LAST);
end;
```

And this is how I call it in the WinProc procedure:

```pascal
function WinProc(hWnd: HWND; Msg: Cardinal; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
  case Msg of
    {...}
    WM_MEASUREITEM:
    begin
      with PMEASUREITEMSTRUCT(lParam)^ do
      begin
        itemWidth := 100;
        itemHeight := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYMENU);
      end;
    end;
    WM_DRAWITEM:
    begin
      with PDRAWITEMSTRUCT(lParam)^ do
      begin
        DrawOpaMenuItem(hwndItem, hDC, itemID, rcItem, itemState);
      end;
    end;
    {...}
  end;
  {...}
  Result := DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
end;
```

The GetMenuString function always returns 0, so in this example all items are drawn with the label "Item".

Why does the call to GetMenuString Does not return the item string?

Comment: What is the value of `TxtLen`?

Comment: @i486 Note that in the code it is defined `if TxtLen <> 0 then ... else ... `, and since I mentioned that all the items are drawn with the inscription "Item", I came to the conclusion that the value of `TxtLen` is set to 0...

Comment: The important thing is how you added the item to the menu. `InsertMenu(..., MF_OWNERDRAW)` items do not have strings at all. From GetMenuString: "If the specified item is not of type MIIM_STRING or MFT_STRING, then the return value is zero."

Comment: @Raymond Indeed, I changed `InsertMenu` to `InsertMenuItem` and it works, but adding the items becomes a little more cumbersome...

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution as @Raymond commented, is to use `InsertMenuItem` instead of `InsertMenu`. Because `MF_STRING` is not `MFT_STRING` with `MIIM_STRING`, and does not associate a retrievable string with an item.